# How to make apply() not drop dimensions?

Tags: arrays, r

I've got a 4-dimensional array that I want to apply a function across without changing the axes:

```
l = letters
a = array(1:2*3*4*5, dim=c(2,3,4,5),dimnames=list(l[1:2],l[3:5],l[6:9],l[10:14]))
id = function(x) x
fx = function(x) sum(x)
```

If I apply a function that does not change the structure I can recover the original dimensions using `aperm`:

```
re = dim(apply(a, c(1,2,4), id)) # 4 2 3 5
aperm(re, match(seq_along(dim(a)), c(3,1,2,4))) # original dims
```

Is there any way to apply a function across a certain dimension retaining the dimensions?

```
re = dim(apply(a, c(1,2,4), fx)) # 2 3 5, dropping 3rd dimension
```

Other functions have an argument `drop` to indicate whether dimensions with `length=1` should be dropped, but this does not.

Comment: In your question, you don't have `l` defined.

Comment: Have you seen the `aaply` function in `plyr`? It provides (among others) `.drop`: *should extra dimensions of length 1 in the output be dropped.